# Bootstrap Embed picture in grid element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have discovered a discrepancy between bootstrap v3.0.0 and the latest version v3.3.0.  I spend most of the day yesterday trying to figure it out and didn't have any luck.  If i embed am image into a grid element with the following code:
HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="page-content" class="application-body-home">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <div id="intro" class="row-fluid">
            <div class="well">
                <div id="introPic" class="media-left">
                <p>
                  <img style="float: left; margin:0px 15px 15px 0px; height: 200px;" src="http://tmacfitness.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Beauty-of-nature-random-4884759-1280-800.jpg" class="img-responsive">

              In ancient manuscripts, another means to divide sentences in into paragraphs was a line break (newline) followed by an initial at the beginning of the next paragraph. An initial is an oversize capital letter, sometimes outdented beyond the margin of text. This style can be seen, for example, in the original Old English manuscript of Beowulf. Outdenting is still used in English typography, though not commonly.[4] Modern English typography usually indicates a new paragraph by indenting the first line. This style can be seen in the (handwritten) United States Constitution from 1787. For additional ornamentation, a hedera leaf or other symbol can be added to the inter-paragraph whitespace, or put in the indentation space.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

#col1 {
  background-color: #f1f2f6;

}
#col1:first-child {
  padding: 0 4px 0 0;
}
#col1:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0 4px;
}
#col1:last-child {
  padding: 0 0 0 4px;
}
.col-inside{
border: solid 1px #000000;
}

#intro{
    border: solid 2px #000000;
  }
```

in v3.3.0 ([v3.3.0 example](http://www.bootply.com/UUg3OgHDSv)) it seems to work, but not in v3.0.0([v3.0.0 example](http://www.bootply.com/U9xzsZDLQS#)).  In v3.0.0 the image does not stay within the `row` it is in when the window is made larger.

Is there a way to make it work in v3.0.0?

Comment: Hmmm, they look the same to me. How wide does the v3.0.0 example need to be to see the difference?

Comment: On my machine if i have the windot at 1045px it looks good and at 1046px the picture extends below the row.

Comment: Not seeing that in Chrome on Win7. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: I just opened the links on a separate machine and they are both loading using v3.3.0.  I guess if you are the author you can change which bootstrap version it is using.  I am using Chrome and Win7 as well.

Comment: I created a new fiddle using 3.0.0 and added `.well{
    overflow:auto;
  }`. Does that fix it?

Comment: Yes it does.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `.well{ overflow:auto; }` to your CSS will allow the parent to encapsulate the descendant elements.